# Почему время от времени происходит ошибка "server status is no status code; ERR: errcode: 28"?

Tags: яндекс-маркет

Периодически (в разное время и не каждый день) получаю вот такие сообщение с ошибками от Яндекса маркета:

> Не удалось получить файл https://site.ru/shop/yandex/genreyml, текст сообщения об ошибке:
>   server status is no status code; ERR: errcode: 28, msg: Operation timed out after 900000 milliseconds with 0 out of -1 bytes received

Хостинг firstvds. Подскажите, где исправить чтобы ошибки больше не появлялись? Ресурсов сервера судя по графикам хватает.

Comment: а тот файл-то доступен?

Comment: да, доступен, предложения попадают в яндекс.

Comment: я бы настроил любой мониторинг и проверил, что сайт/сервер доступен всегда. Может просто сайт иногда "ложится" или сеть. В любом случае, всегда можно скачать accesslog/errorlog и посмотреть в указанное яндексом время (или просто посчитать статистику посещений и проверить, нет ли провалов)